# Removing of specific line in text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am working on an option which will be able to remove the line specified if the user types in the exact title and author.

However I will not be able to make it work.

My function contents are shown below

```
fnRemoveBook()
{
echo"Title: "
read Title
echo"Author: "
read Author

if grep -Fqe "$Title:$Author" BookDB.txt; then
    sed -i '/"$Title:$Author"/ d' BookDB.txt
    echo "Book removed successfully!"
else
    echo "Error! Book does not exist!"
fi
}
```

The BookDB contents are shown below

```
Hello World:Andreas:10:5:2
Teaching:Mary Ann:50:23:5
```

After I have keyed in "Hello World" for title and "Andreas" for author, the program will be able to enter into the loop and echo-ed Book removed successfully.

However I checked the BookDB.txt the line has not been removed yet and I wonder why.

I hope I will be able to get some answers out here as I have been doing research on the internet but still have no answers at the moment.

Thanks in advance to those who helped! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass a `bash` variable (two, actually) into a sub-program (`sed`), but surrounding the expression you're passing in single-quotes, which does no parameter expansion. That means that `sed` is literally seeing `$Title:$Author`. Try putting the whole `sed` expression in double-quotes:

```
sed -i "/$Title:$Author/d" BookDB.txt
```

This will allow `bash` to expand `$Title` and `$Author` before they get into `sed`.

Comment: Thanks to you guys! Solved my problem!
I am so sorry as I have been trying to search examples/questions/answers on the internet however I have not seen any which is similar to my case yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes does not interpolate variables. Try something like this -

```
fnRemoveBook()
{
echo "Title: "
read Title
echo "Author: "
read Author

if grep -Fqe "$Title:$Author" BookDB.txt; then
    sed -i "/$Title:$Author/ d" BookDB.txt    # <---- Changes made here
    echo "Book removed successfully!"
else
    echo "Error! Book does not exist!"
fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you guys! Solved my problem!
I am so sorry as I have been trying to search examples/questions/answers on the internet however I have not seen any which is similar to my case yet.

Comment: @Andres You don't have to be sorry. You posted a good question. You explained your issue, showed what you have tried and stated your desired result. It's good to hear that your issue has been resolved and you are good to go!! :) Good luck!!